# Program only printing out/receiving every other packet

Tags: java, sockets, udp, packets

I'm supposed to send packets of a file over to a server which then prints it out. The problem i have is that it prints out only every odd number (0-nothing, 1- text, 2- nothing, 4-text etc..). This gets done in the server class. Can anyone see what he problem is?

> Client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Client myCli = new Client();
    myCli.run();

}

public void run() throws Exception {

    Socket mySkt = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
    PrintStream myPS = new PrintStream(mySkt.getOutputStream());



    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Thormode/Dropbox/Skole 2013-2014/java/da/src/da/tekst.txt"));

    while (in.ready()) {
        String s = in.readLine();
        myPS.println(s);
    }
    in.close();



    //BufferedReader myBR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mySkt.getInputStream()));

    //String temp = myBR.readLine();
    //System.out.println(temp);

    mySkt.close();
    myPS.close();

}
}
```

> Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server myServ = new Server();
    myServ.run();
}

public void run() throws Exception {

    ServerSocket mySS = new ServerSocket(9999);
    Socket SS_accept = mySS.accept();
    BufferedReader SS_BF = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            SS_accept.getInputStream()));
    int i = 0;
    String[] array = new String[10];

    while (SS_BF.readLine() != null) {

        array[i] = SS_BF.readLine();
        i++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        String temp = array[j];
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

    SS_accept.close();
    mySS.close();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will read two lines a loop:

```
String[] array = new String[10];

while (SS_BF.readLine() != null) {   // reads a line and forgets it's value

    array[i] = SS_BF.readLine();   // reads every second line and puts it into the array
    i++;
}
```

So you have to do it like this:

```
String[] array = new String[10];
String line = SS_BF.readLine();   // read first line and store it to 'line'

while (line != null) {
    array[i++] = line;            // set 'line' to array
    line = SS_BF.readLine();      // read next line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (SS_BF.readLine() != null) {

    array[i] = SS_BF.readLine();
    i++;
}
```

You are calling SS_BF.readLine twice. It discards the first line because of this.

```
while ((String line = SS_BF.readLine()) != null) {

    array[i] = line;
    i++;
}
```